# stuck threads in weblogic while trying to communicate over RMI

Tags: multithreading, weblogic, rmi

Our application is running in an 8 node Weblogic cluster and is trying to communicate to an RMI server. The threads doing so get stuck due to an error in the RMI server. We're trying to solve that, but the problem is that until then, the stuck threads slow down the application eventually bringing the whole cluster on its knees.

My question is 'how can we from the client side make sure that the threads get released ?'

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Implementation details:
- Weblogic 10.0MP2, cluster with 8 nodes
- Java 1.5

Thread dump snippet:

```
"[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '15' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon prio=3 tid=0x03808610 nid=0x1c9 runnable [0
x3ed4e000..0x3ed4faf0]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
        - locked <0xa0a515a0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:241)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:189)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:126)
        at com.kpno.in.iac.CustomerBridge.CustomerBridge.RemoteDecorator_Stub.sendMessage(Unknown Source)
        at com.kpno.in.iac.CustomerBridge.RMIServer.CustomerBridgeProxy.sendMessage(Unknown Source)
```

Application snippet (decompiled):

```
public final class RemoteDecorator_Stub extends RemoteStub
  implements ...
{
  ...

  public Map sendMessage(String paramString1, String paramString2, Map paramMap)
    throws InvalidActionException, ProcessingException, PropagationException, ResponseException, TimeoutException, RemoteException
  {
    try
    {
      Object localObject = this.ref.invoke(this, $method_sendMessage_2, new Object[] { paramString1, paramString2, paramMap }, 6494150482049562645L);
      return (Map)localObject;
    }
    catch ...
```

UPDATE

I've tried to make it work with the JNDI lookup as Tolis proposed, but until now I was not successful. I am wondering what the url should be. Retrieving from RMI naming is done as follows: 
java.rmi.Naming.lookup("//host:port/FactoryObject")

How do I translate this to a JNDI url? I've tried with t3 as the protocol and with iiop. Nothing worked. I always get a naming exception.

In case of t3 I get this exception:
[Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: t3://host:port: Destination unreachable; nested exception is: java.io.IOException: Empty server reply; No available router to destination]

In case of iiop I get this exception:
javax.naming.CommunicationException: Cannot connect to ORB [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No]

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **weblogic.rmi.clientTimeout** setting in order to avoid thread stuck situations when the target server is experiencing problems.

**EDITED:**

Another solution which is useful when you are trying to read from a socket and you are not getting any response from the server is the following:

An RMISocketFactory instance is used by the RMI runtime in order to obtain client and server sockets for RMI calls. An application may use the setSocketFactory method to request that the RMI runtime use its socket factory instance instead of the default implementation.

Implementation example:

```
RMISocketFactory.setSocketFactory(new RMISocketFactory()
{
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
        Socket s = new Socket();
        s.setSoTimeout(timeoutInMilliseconds);
        s.setSoLinger(false, 0);
        s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), timeoutInMilliseconds);
        return s;
    }

    public ServerSocket createServerSocket(int port) throws IOException {
        return new ServerSocket(port);
    }
});
```

The setSocketFactory sets the global socket factory from which RMI gets sockets.

Comment: Thanks Tolis. I cannot yet confirm that this is the answer that works for me, but it sure sounds like it. I will do so as soon as I can.

Comment: Please note that the configuration of 10 seconds in the example that I provided is random. You will have to adjust the weblogic.rmi.clientTimeout with a value that fits to your case. Thank you.

Comment: I've tried to make it work with the JNDI lookup as Tolis proposed, but until now I was not successful. I am wondering what the url should be. Retrieving from RMI naming is done as follows: java.rmi.Naming.lookup("//host:port/FactoryObject")

How do I translate this to a JNDI url? I've tried with t3 as the protocol and with iiop. Nothing worked. I always get a naming exception.

Any ideas ?

Comment: But this requires modification of the RMI server implementation doesn't it ? Or can this also be done from the client ?